# Make height responsive / let it stay in ratio

Tags: html, css

Currently I'am working on a responsive image-slider but there is something I need to know before I can make my slider completely responsive, and that is how can I code that the automaticly adjust to the width(Like that it stays in a ratio, 16:9 for example)? My code is something like this (simplified).

```
    <div style="width: 100px; height: 50px;" id="container">
<img src="" style="width: 100%, height:100%" id="inside">
</div>
```

I already tried like padding-bottom 70% etc. but that doesn't work for me because (I think) the inside is like relative to the containers height not padding?

Comment: Are the images added as actual image elements (`<img src>`) or as `background-images` to the `div`'s you added in your question?

Comment: Yep there are image elements involved, see the div#inside as an Image (I will edit this)

Comment: are you looking for responsive embed ? https://jsfiddle.net/g9u182jr/

Answer (score 2):

To keep the ratio, you should start with

width: 100% and height: auto

Try to make a working fiddle to better explain what you need

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vvkm8031/ Well here is a fiddle and what to suppose to happen is when the screen width decrease to a certain point where the slider gets of the screen. Then there sould be a breakpoint that make the css like that so the size of the slider decreases in a ratio. I hope you will understand

Answer (score 1):

To keep the image in ratio, you can use

```css
#container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

#container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<img src="http://florisdeboer.com/Screenshot%20(80).png" id="inside">
</div>
```